# showing button based upon session variables not working

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to show a button based upon my session variables. 
When user with userlevel admin logs in a certain button shows what other users are not allowed to see.
However I cannot get it to works.

All session variables are stored and when I print them it shows me the following:

```
Array
(
    [loggedin] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [username] => Admini
    [userlevel] => admin
)
```

In my page the code that should show the button goes as followed:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] == 'admin') : ?>
<a href=""><img src="images/trash.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/> 
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

No error message and no button is showing.

Any help please

Comment: had a typo, made correction in original post above

Comment: Try adding an else branch, and see if it goes into that. If not, check the generated HTML code, not what the browser renders. Maybe it doesn’t “show” anything because the image path is wrong, or something like that.

Comment: i've looked into the sourcecode and nothing is showing.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, it shows more details. Like maybe there's a space at the end of `admin`.

Comment: The code looks fine, so the only explanation is that the comparison is failing.

Comment: Are you doing session_start() before it hits the code above?

Comment: session_start() is used on top of the page, first line of code.

Comment: I noticed now that an old pieces of code is loaded, how is this possible??
not the entire page but pieces of code

Comment: I was going to suggest changing the  ==  to  !=  which would either show a button or indicate you have something more fundamentally wrong.  Although if you are seeing wrong code, I would add "It is not unknown for a programmer to be editing code in the wrong folder"

Comment: I am editing in the correct folder in the correct file, no question there.
when i change == into != all users gets the button

Comment: That concludes the problem is $_SESSION['userlevel'] does not contain the word 'admin' at the point where it does the check. Like @Barmar said, you may have a rogue space lurking, or the value is altered elsewhere, or the sessions variables are not available.

Comment: I would add something like <?php echo "|".$_SESSION['userlevel']."|"; ?> just before the IF just to see what it contains at that point.  (The pipes would highlight any spaces)